# Furnace problem

Tags: heater

My furnace kicks on like it should when it reaches temp it shuts off but maybe a minute later the fan kicks on, runs 10 seconds and shuts off it does this three times before it stops. My brother says it's the switch not the reset but the other one but I don't know what it's called to try replacing it. Does this sound like it's the problem?

Comment: Please explain what type of furnace you have.  Fuel type: oil, gas, electric, geothermal, coal...  Hot water, Forced hot air, steam?  Maybe even the make and model?  It might help.

Comment: Should the fan run after the furnace normally? I know that my fan kicks on for a minute or so after the furnace to circulate the air. If it's kicking on and off variably, then it could be a loose wire contact to the fan (or from the fan to the control board). If it's exactly 10 seconds each time (roughly), then it could be a bad timer or setting switch. And last, it could be an override telling it to turn off for one reason or another. Hope that helps, but I believe we'll need more info to help online.

Answer (score 1):

I find his often on electric heaters Most have temp switches, when the temp is high enough the fan runs even if the thermostat is not calling for heat. This cools the unit down and it shuts down then some residual heat left in the unit makes its way to the temp switch and turns on the fan again. This is a safety if working as I describe and the unit is working properly.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening - a switch based on the temperature of the heat exchanger is being repeatedly triggered as the exchanger cools, the fan stops, stored heat in the exchanger diffuses, the switch warms, the fan comes back on...

How-why-what may vary a lot with the make, model and era of your furnace.

The simplest of these just depend on a sufficiently large differential in "where the switch cuts out" and where it cuts on. Replacing the switch should fix that.

More complex systems may have an "after-run timer" that could (should, evidently) have its run time extended to more fully cool the exchanger.